# How to populate a custom not mapped field in a overridden form in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I use Sylius 1.12.7 with Symfony 6.2.10 (PHP 8.0).
I managed to customize the new/edit form of a Taxon and I can save the associated products, but I don't know how to load the associated products.

've extended the Taxon form type:

```
# src/Form/Extension/TaxonTypeExtension.php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use App\EventSubscriber\TaxonOnSubmitSubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Sylius\Bundle\TaxonomyBundle\Form\Type\TaxonType;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Repository\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class TaxonTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    )
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
            ->addEventSubscriber(new TaxonOnSubmitSubscriber($this->entityManager, $this->productRepository));
    }

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [TaxonType::class];
    }

}
```

so here the subscriber:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Entity\Taxonomy\Taxon;
use App\Entity\Product\Product;
use App\Entity\Product\ProductTaxon;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\PostSubmitEvent;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Repository\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductAutocompleteChoiceType;

class TaxonOnSubmitSubscriber implements \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;


    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface     $entityManager,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    )
    {
        /** @var EntityManagerInterface entityManager */
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'formPreSetData',
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'formPostSubmit',
        ];
    }

    public function formPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $taxon = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $products = ($this->productRepository->findByTaxon($taxon) ?? []);

        //todo: load the products associated to the taxon in the ProductAutocompleteChoiceType, where do I put these $products ???

        $form->add('products', ProductAutocompleteChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'app.form.taxon.associate_products',
            'multiple' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);

    }

    public function formPostSubmit(PostSubmitEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var Taxon $taxon */
        $taxon = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $allFormData = $form?->all();
        if (isset($allFormData['products'])) {
            $products = $allFormData['products']?->getData();
            if (!empty($products) && count($products) > 0) {
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    /** @var Product $product */
                    if (!$product->hasTaxon($taxon)) {
                        $productTaxon = new ProductTaxon();
                        $productTaxon->setTaxon($taxon);
                        $productTaxon->setProduct($product);
                        $product->addProductTaxon($productTaxon);
                        $this->entityManager->persist($product);
                        $this->entityManager->flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So I don't know if my code is beautiful but saving the associated products works pretty well: for simplicity I just save all selected products without deleting the old ones.
**My question is how to leverage the component `ProductAutocompleteChoiceType` and load the products associated with the taxonomy I'm editing (see the //todo in the code...) ?**

I've tried in the `formPreSetData()` setting the data in the `'products'` field:
`$form->get('products')->setData($products)`but `setData()` expects a collection but `$products` is an array.
I expect to see the autocomplete field populated with products associated to the taxon.